# Kinesis Analytics Session or Stagger Window Batching Without Aggregation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I'm looking to use Kinesis Data Analytics (or some other AWS managed service) to batch records based on a filter criteria. The idea would be that as records come in, we'd start a session window and batch any matching records for 15 min.

The stagger window is exactly what we'd like except we're not looking to aggregate the data, but rather just return the records all together.

Ideally...

```
100 records spread over 15 min. (20 matching criteria) with first one at 10:02
                                 |
                                 v
At 10:17, the 20 matching records would be sent to the destination
```

I've tried doing something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM" (
    "device_id" INTEGER, 
    "child_id" INTEGER, 
    "domain" VARCHAR(32),
    "category_id" INTEGER,
    "posted_at" DOUBLE,
    "block" TIMESTAMP
);

-- Create pump to insert into output 
CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "STREAM_PUMP" AS INSERT INTO "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM"

-- Select all columns from source stream
SELECT STREAM 
    "device_id", 
    "child_id", 
    "domain", 
    "category_id", 
    "posted_at",
    FLOOR("SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001".ROWTIME TO MINUTE) as block
FROM "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001"
WHERE "category_id" = 888815186
WINDOWED BY STAGGER (
    PARTITION BY "child_id", FLOOR("SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001".ROWTIME TO MINUTE) 
    RANGE INTERVAL '15' MINUTE);
```

I continue to get errors for all the columns not in the aggregation:

```
From line 6, column 5 to line 6, column 12: Expression 'domain' is not being used in PARTITION BY sub clause of WINDOWED BY clause
```

Kinesis Firehose was a suggested solution, but it's a blind window to all `child_id`, so it could possibly cut up a session in to multiple and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Any suggestions? Feels like this might not be the right tool.

Answer (score 0):

try `LAST_VALUE("domain") as domain` in the select clause.